# How do I add a Application_End handler without using global.asax?

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule, application-end

I'm writing an http module, and I want to add a method that is called when (and only when) the appdomain gets recycled. I don't want to add anything to global.asax, I want to do it programatically within the http module.

However, there doesn't seem to be an `End` event on the instance of `HttpApplication` passed in the module's `Init` method. How can I subscribe to the `Application_End` event?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve in at the point the app domain gets recycled?

Comment: Sending off some data to a webservice that has been stored in memory

Comment: I need save logs on application end

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload +=new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_DomainUnload);
```

This I believe is more **accurate** than `Application.End` which should cover the recycles.